# Assigning a setting variable into a local variable in ftl

Tags: freemarker

I am new to Ftl and am working with dates in ftl. I know that I can get the current year using

```
    ${.now?string("yyyy")}
```

However I want to assign the year into a variable. On using

```
<#assign year = ${.now?string("yyyy")}>
```

I get a syntax error. Can someone help?

Comment: Within a freemarker tag, you have to use it without `${}` envelope, i.e. `<#assign year = .now?string("yyyy") />`.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek yes I tried that and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I get this syntax error, and unless you are using an old version, you should too:

> Syntax error in template "adhoc.ftl" in line 1, column 17: You can't
>   use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus,
>   instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only
>   needed where otherwise static text is expected, i.e, outside
>   FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)

Comment: @iwein It *does* answer the question.

Comment: @iwein Huh? The quoted error message says, "instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression". That's the solution to the problem. The other parts of it are the explanation.

Comment: removed my comments, I think you can remove the answer, then we can remove the question and the world would be a tidier place.

Answer (score 0):

The correct assignment is

```
<#assign year = .now?string("yyyy") />
```